# Cross compile OpenVPN with PolarSSL?

Tags: linux, gcc, ssl, openvpn

I'm trying to cross compile OpenVPN 2.3.4 with PolarSSL 1.3.7 for ARM on Debian Wheezy. PolarSSL is compiled and installed in my home directory, but OpenVPN can't find the libraries and headers, so this error message is shown:

```
checking polarssl version... configure: error: PolarSSL 1.2.x required and must be 1.2.10 or later
```

PolarSSL has been configured like this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/smith9073/polarssl -D ENABLE_PROGRAMS=OFF ../polarssl-1.3.7/
```

This is how I have tried to tell OpenVPN about the location of PolarSSL:

```
CFLAGS="-I/home/smith9073/polarssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/smith9073/polarssl/lib" ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-crypto-library=polarssl
checking polarssl version... configure: error: PolarSSL 1.2.x required and must be 1.2.10 or later

LIBS="-lpolarssl" CFLAGS="-I/home/smith9073/polarssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/smith9073/polarssl/lib" ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-crypto-library=polarssl
checking polarssl version... configure: error: PolarSSL 1.2.x required and must be 1.2.10 or later

CFLAGS="-I/home/smith9073/polarssl/include" LIBS="-lpolarssl/home/smith9073/polarssl/lib" ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-crypto-library=polarssl
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

CFLAGS="-I/home/smith9073/polarssl/include" LIBS="-l/home/smith9073/polarssl/lib" ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-crypto-library=polarssl
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

POLARSSL_CFLAGS="-I/home/smith9073/polarssl/include" POLARSSL_LIBS="-l/home/smith9073/polarssl/lib" ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-crypto-library=polarssl
checking polarssl version... configure: error: PolarSSL 1.2.x required and must be 1.2.10 or later

POLARSSL_CFLAGS="-I/home/smith9073/polarssl/include" POLARSSL_LIBS="-lpolarssl/home/smith9073/polarssl/lib" ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-crypto-library=polarssl
checking polarssl version... configure: error: PolarSSL 1.2.x required and must be 1.2.10 or later
```

Does anyone know why OpenVPN can't find PolarSSL?

Comment: Did you ever end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

The PolarSSL 1.3.x release broke API with the 1.2.x series and OpenVPN hasn't updated yet to the new API, so for the time being you'll have to use PolarSSL 1.2.x or the other crypto backend (OpenSSL).